# Problems with a basic proof in Aumann Structures

Tags: elementary-set-theory, modal-logic

I am pretty sure this is more than trivial, but I have a problem with the proof of a basic results in Aumann structures (this is related to a more general problem I have with proofs that involve equality chains).

Here, $K$ stands for the *knowledge operator*, and $E$ for an arbitrary event subset of a set $\Omega$ of *states of the worlds*.

Assume the following:

1. $K E \subset E$
2. $\sim K E  \subset K \sim K E $

then $K E = KK E$ follows.

Aumann states that the result can be obtained in the following way:
$\sim KE = K \sim KE$, so $KE = \sim K \sim KE$, so $KKE = K \sim K \sim KE=\sim K \sim KE = KE$.

As I wrote I do have a general problem with proofs involving equality chains. Anyway, the way in which I try to establish a result like this is the following. Basically I have to prove that $KKE \subset KE$ and $KE \subset KKE$ both hold.
[For what I got, it's only after that you establish it, that you present it as a chain of equalities]-

Now, $KKE \subset KE$ is trivial, but I don't see how I can prove the converse.
What am I missing?

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

[The original article by Aumann, of which I use the notation, can be found [here](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/raumann/pdf/Interactive%20epistemology1.pdf) - the problem I have is between page 267 and page 270]

Comment: I was not completely sure about which were the most appropriate tags.

Comment: One key obesrvation is that 2. is actually an equality, as because of 1., $K\sim KE\subset \sim KE$.

Comment: Actually, I am almost ashamed... now I see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can prove it this way.

$\forall w \in KE$, $I(w) \subset E$. $I$ is the information function induced by the knowledge operator $K$.

If $I(w) \not \subset KE$, then $\exists w^{'} \in I(w)$ s.t. $w^{'} \in \sim KE \subset K\sim KE$. Then $I(w^{'}) = I(w) \subset \sim KE$. Contradiction.

Thus, $I(w) \subset KE$. This means $w \in KKE$